# returned float pointer not storing data permanently

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a simple program in C to output a float as an int and in hex, etc.

For this assignment, I'm not allowed to change anything in main.

I have a function, getNextFloat(&f), that takes the address of 'float f;' calls scanf to get the float value, and then returns a pointer to the new value of f, which is sent to my print function (which converts the float value into hex and other representations).

My problem is that when I run the program, when I call scanf in the function getNextFloat and input a number, if I immediately print *f inside the getNextFloat function it prints fine, but if I return *f and print 'f' in the print function, its value is 0 no matter what number I input in getNextFloat. I'm not sure why the value of 'f' isn't being saved and seems to be local to getNextFloat.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char *studentName = "me";

// report whether machine is big or small endian:

void bigOrSmallEndian()
{
        // irrelevant to question; contains code to report 'endian-ness'
}

// note: the following 3 comments are instructions from the teacher
// get next float using scanf()
// returns 1 (success) or 0 (failure)
// if call succeeded, return float value via f pointer:

int getNextFloat(float *f)
{
        float fl;

        scanf("%f", &fl);
        f = &fl;
        printf("%f", *f);
        return *f;
}

void printNumberData(float f)
{
        // note: function is incomplete, trying to fix this pointer thing first

        printf("%10f", f);
        printf("%10x\n", f);
}

// do not change this function in any way
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        float   f;
        int     nValues;

        printf("CS201 - A01 - %s\n\n", studentName);
        bigOrSmallEndian();
        for (;;) {
                if(argc == 1)
                        printf("> ");
                nValues = getNextFloat(&f);
                if(! nValues) {
                        printf("bad input\n");
                        while (getchar() != '\n');
                        continue;
                        }
                printNumberData(f);
                if(f == 0.0)
                        break;
                }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

As an example, here's what I get when I run the code:

```
byte order: little-endian

> 9
9.000000  0.000000  7ffffff5
```

The first value it prints, 9.000000, is the tester call to printf that I put in my getNextFloat function to show that it's scanning correctly and the problem lies elsewhere.

The next two values are what is apparently stored in f when the print function is called.

Thanks for the insight

Comment: Recheck `getNextFloat()` - it's not doing what you think it does...

Comment: From the instructions in the comments,  `getNextFloat(float*f)` can simply be `return scanf("%f", f) == 1;` (the usefulness of said-function left to the imagination).

Comment: Oh humdinger. I see it now. I wasn't sure what to do with the 0 or 1 instruction. Thank you both very much

Answer (score 3):

Let's run through what's happening in `getNextFloat`

```
int getNextFloat( float *f ) {
        float fl; // declare a stack variable named fl, containing junk at this point
        scanf( "%f", &fl ); // read a value into fl
        f = &fl; // f now points to fl, which is on the stack
        return *f; // return the value of fl truncated to an integer
} // pop fl from the stack, the next thing to be pushed onto the stack will overwrite the contents of what f was pointing to
```

Keep in mind, any modification to `f` *as a value* from inside the function, will not modify any value outside the function. f is effectively a local variable at this point, unless you *dereference* it and write to the memory that `f` is pointing to (which should be the variable named `f` in `main`)

What you want to do, is change the `f = &fl;` line into `*f = fl;`

Answer (score -1):

Do not use tabs for indentation, as each editor
has the tab stops/tab width set differently.
I.E. use (say) 4 spaces for readability for indentation.

this line, in getNextFloat()

```
f = &fl;
```

is backwards.

It should be:

```
*f = fl;
```

Remember that the task is to return a 1 if scanf successful, else return 0

overall the function should be:

```
int getNextFloat(float *f)
{
        float fl;
        int success = 0;

        success = scanf("%f", &fl);

        // always place literal on left
        // so an error like '=' will be caught by the compiler
        if(1 == success )
        { // then scanf successful
            *f = fl;
            //printf("%f", *f);
        }
        else
        { // else, overwrite possible EOF value in success
            success = 0;
        }
        return success;
} // end function: getNextFloat
```